# I'm half of a hundred

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay

I'm half of a hundred and both halves of a Belgian detective, two thirds of solar exposure and one eighth of an Age.

If you know who I am, post your answer, plus your explanation for each of the clues.

Good luck! (Although of course luck has nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Per the [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5156/57742), I edited the title to make it clearer what the puzzle is about. @clayRay, if you prefer the previous title, you can roll back my edit, or you can set one yourself :)

Comment: Thanks @PilsNot3, I think you made the title more intriguing, which is good.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think you are

> Tin

I'm half of a hundred

> The atomic number of tin is 50

and both halves of a Belgian detective,

> [Tintin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tintin_(character))

two thirds of solar exposure

> Tan - contains two of the three letters of tin.

and one eighth of an Age.

> [Bronze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_Age) - which is roughly 1/8th tin.

Comment: Dammit, I was thinking of [the *other* Belgian detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercule_Poirot)!

Comment: @Rand al'Thor "I'm not French, I'm Belgian!"

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's what popped into my head, as well...

Comment: Tintin was a reporter for _Le Petit Vingtieme_, not a detective

Comment: @Randal'Thor: David Suchet will always be my go-to Poirot, but your comment lead me to learn about [Bilbo Poirot](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gTC5ZV11_LI/WdW57Det4sI/AAAAAAAAMs8/Hqo5jXFIN0QbLnVv12fIXPeNU6pRCtu-gCLcBGAs/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-10-04%2Bat%2B9.47.03%2BPM.png).

Comment: @Randal'Thor You mean Thomson and Thompson? That was my immediate idea, with the "I am half".

Comment: @nzaman, Maybe not professionally, but he played the role.

Comment: Congratulations @hexonimo, you got the answer and all the clues.

Comment: @nzaman, yes, that was supposedly his profession, but he seemed to do a lot more sleuthing than writing newspaper articles